# Proof through Induction

Tags: proof-verification, induction

$\forall n\in\mathbb{N}: n\ge 1 \rightarrow 2^n\le 2^{n+1}-2^{n-1}-1.$

I know the basic part so I won't type it in here, and here is my inductive steps:

$2^{k+1}=2^k\cdot 2 \le 2(2^{k+1}-2^{k-1}-1)$

$2^{k+1} \le 2^{k+2} - 2^k -2$

I know that $2^{k+2}$ and $2^k$ is correct and I can assume $n = k+1$ to get $2^{n+1}-2^{n-1}$

But I don't know how to change $-2 $ to $ -1$ and make it as $2^{n+1}-2^{n-1}-1.$

Comment: $x-2 \lt x-1\,$

Comment: @Ed_4434 Dividing by 2 won't help since the Induction hypothesis is $2^k\leq 2^{k+1}-2^{k-1}-1$ and what is needed to show is that $2^{k+1}\leq 2^{k+2}-2^k-1$. So you only use that: $2^{k+1}\leq 2^{k+2}-2^k-2 < 2^{k+2}-2^k-1$.

Answer (score 1):

why do you need to change -2 to -1?
you already have:

$2^{k+1} \leq 2^{k+2} - 2^k - 2 \leq 2^{k+2} - 2^k - 1$

Note, dividing by 2 will not work, because you will get the induction assumption... you need to prove $2^{k+1}$ not $2^k$, in fact you assumed the case $2^k$ and used it